# make distance between text and headsepline

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

with a two-line section name in the headline, the distance between text and line is too small. How can i change it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,                % Schriftgröße
DIV=calc                            % Automatischer Satzspiegel
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Aktiviert EC-Schriftarten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Dateikodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         % Deutsche Einstellung
\usepackage{lmodern}                % Latin Modern
\usepackage{blindtext}

%% Geometrieeigenschaften
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}

%% Zeilenabstand auf 1,5
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

%% Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearscrheadfoot                                   % Voreinstellungen resetten
\ihead[]{\parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{\headmark}}       % Zeilenumbruch nach 60% der Länge
\ohead[]{Name}                                      % Name oben rechts
\cfoot[]{-\pagemark-}                               % Seitenzahl unten mitte
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}               % Serifenlose Kopf- und Fußzeile

\begin{document}
    \section{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Überschriften}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

### ** Edit by Manuel Kuehner (smaller MWE)**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top = 30mm, 
    showframe = true,
    }

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearscrheadfoot 
\ihead[]{\parbox[t]{.3\textwidth}{\headmark}}     
\begin{document}
    \section{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the optional argument of `section` to have its title on a single line for headers and table of contents.

Comment: When a section is too long, it looks "wrong" because between the section and my name is no gap. Therefore i break it.

Comment: I added a smaller MWE and removed the German example text.

Comment: @Bernard meant, that you can use `section[short version]{normal version}` in order to avoid long section titles. That's not a direct answer to your question but it is an alternative approach to the problem.

Comment: Ok, i didn't know about that option. This solution is a good way,too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can not use the optional argument of `\section` to avoid a header entry that is to too long for one line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top = 30mm, 
    showframe = true,% to show the page layout
    }

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% depraceted command replaced
\ihead{%
  \parbox
    [b]% use b(ottom) instead t(op)
    [\ht\strutbox]% to avoid the warning regarding head height
    {.3\textwidth}{\raggedright\headmark}% \raggedright to avoid underfull hboxes
 }
\begin{document}
    \section{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screen shot]

---

You could also use option `head lines=2`. Then you can remove the second optional argument of `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
head lines=2% added
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[a4paper,
]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top = 30mm, 
    showframe = true,% to show the page layout
    }

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% depraceted command replaced
\ihead{%
  \parbox
    [b]% use b(ottom) instead t(op)
    {.3\textwidth}{\raggedright\headmark}% \raggedright to avoid underfull hboxes
 }
\begin{document}
    \section{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: screen shot]

---

Note, there is also an option `headings=optiontohead`. Then you can use a short version of the section title only for the page header.

```
\documentclass[12pt,
headings=optiontohead% added
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top = 30mm, 
    showframe = true,
    }

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% depraceted command replaced
\ihead{\headmark}% changed
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \section[Only Test]{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

With one of the options `headings=optiontohead`, `headings=optiontoheadandtoc`, headings=`optiontotoc` you can also use different entries in page header and in TOC.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
headings=optiontoheadandtoc% added
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top = 30mm, 
    showframe = true,
    }

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% depraceted command replaced
\ihead{\headmark}% changed
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \section[head={Version in page header},tocentry={Version in table of contents}]
      {Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
    \Blindtext
    \section[Only Test]{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test }
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I didn't see you answer until I posted mine (regarding the `b` option).

Answer (score 1):

- If you use `[b]` option instead of `[t]` option in `\parbox` then it looks nicer.
- In addition, I used the solution recommended by use **@Bernard** in the comments (short version of section).

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% Based on https://komascript.de/node/249 (post from 2019-02-27)
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Uncomment to remove borders (borders are for debugging)
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead[]{\parbox[b]{.3\textwidth}{\headmark}}   
\ohead{ohead}
\ifoot{ifoot}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
% Without optional argument for \section
\section{Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title }
\Blindtext

% With optional argument for \section
\section[Short section Title]{Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title Long Section Title }
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]